# Administrative level ShapeFiles

Tags: shapefile

I need shapefiles for all administrative levels like country level, state level, division level and city level for all countries of the world?

Answer (score 4):

You can get those from these source

http://www.diva-gis.org/Data

http://www.gadm.org/

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/